# service worker caching issues on netlify/cloudfront/CDN

Tags: javascript, caching, cdn, service-worker, netlify

I use a service worker to cache my PWA.
Everything is working fine on my VPS. 
Now, when i want to host on Netlify, caching breaks due to their CDN.

"./script.js"

becomes

"https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/js/5ae4b88dedf0edb18f2281d6c6b0339b122ad0/.../script.js"

so that the file is not found in the sw-cache. Obviously, that breaks offline functionality.

Is there a solution for caching with CDNs?

Comment: The easy answer is don't use asset optimization in your site's build settings, as that will cause deployment of some assets to cloudfront rather than being served at the usual path under your custom domain or netlify hostname.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep the asset optimization enabled, you can try loading your script.js with the `data-dont-bundle` attribute, like:

`<script data-dont-bundle src="/script.js"></script>`

This attribute will tell netlify not to optimize that file.